# Em anexo ou segue anexo qual o certo?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Em ambientes corporativo é muito comum o uso do "anexo", mas qual a forma correta para empregar o uso do mesmo ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ambas as formas estão corretas (embora os puristas digam que só "segue o anexo" é correto), mas têm diferenças sutis de significado.

***Em anexo*** é uma locução que funciona como advérbio, indicando o modo como algo (o sujeito da frase) segue: `Segue em anexo [como anexo] o documento solicitado.`

***Anexo*** pode ser usado tanto como advérbio (`O documento segue anexo`) ou como substantivo (`Esqueci de incluir o anexo`). Em ambas as situações, deve concordar com o verbo: `Os documentos seguem anexos`.